# VUE 3 array not updating reactively but array[index] is

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3

So I am having this issue when I am trying to link an updating array of objects to a konva circle. The issue isnt getting the circles to appear, but what seems to be happening is that within this for loop to update the players locations based on the "tick" I am setting the array[index].x to a specific value. When I console.log these values they are updating properly. However, when I console.log(array) itself it logs the very last calculated value of the loop.

The players array is defined as such

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      roundNumber: 1,
      players: [],
```

and these values are pushed on setup for each player in the json

```
        let tempObj = round.teamCT[id]
        tempObj.x = 0;
        tempObj.y = 0;
        tempObj.team = "CT"
        this.players.push(tempObj)
```

how I am editing values

```
        console.log(this.players);
        console.log(this.players[index]);
        this.players[index]['x'] = (x-info.x0)*k/info.scale;
        this.players[index]['y'] = (info.y0-y)*k/info.scale;
        console.log(this.players);
        console.log(this.players[index]);
```

You can see in this screenshot that the array itself is updating very differently then the array[index]:

[image: Console.log]

Ive tried adding a watch: on the array itself and that only toggled once, not every time it updates.
Ive looked into Vue.set but that was removed in vue3 and seems to be the best answer so far.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Is the problem that the player objects are not reactive or the array? I'm also confused about your screenshot, in your code, it says you log the array and then one player, but the image shows one player and then the array, indicating that those lines do not belong to the same cycle. When I look at the one pair that is an array/player sequence, the data matches. Or am I missing something?

Comment: So @MoritzRingler turns out I am dumb and didn't realize that the console.log is fetching the data when I hit the dropdown arrow, not when it is logged. This was something that I wasn't aware of, and that is why everything was confusing. It turns out the code that I had was reactive but appeared not to be due to that console.log issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since `Vue.set` doesn't exist anymore, you can do this

```javascript
const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.players));
clone[index].x = "foo";
this.players = clone;
```